# Use JSON from API in html

Tags: json

I am using a RESTful API to get data out of a database such as firstname, lastname etc.  The API gives me the data in JSON and I want to use some of it in a webpage.

For example, I want to print:

```
Welcome firstname lastname.
```

using the data from the JSON string.

How do I do this?

Comment: Where are you accessing the REST API?  from Javascript?  or Server-side?  Please specify any languages/frameworks.

Comment: It's using the OAuth protocol.  I have an html form where I collect a user name and password.  I pass that to the API (using a PHP library provided by the service provider).  The API returns a well formed JSON string which contains name, address type data.  I want to take some of it and display it back to the visitor on the landing page after they have logged in.  Would javascript work best for this?  If so how do I format a simple output such as "Welcome [firstname] [lastname]?

Comment: btw this might help you: https://github.com/viscocent/JSON2HTML

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Assuming "myJSONtext" is well formed JSON, you can get an object representing the data with an eval:

var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')')

Comment: Using eval is generally frowned upon for security reasons because executable code can get through.

Comment: The JSON is coming from your webservice - what malicious code is going to get into there?  (assuming you are sanitizing inputs going into your database)

Comment: The eval was assumed to be done against sanitized JSON, as mentioned by russau.

Comment: As Douglas Crockford often points out, your server may be trusted, but not necessarily competent. Or it maybe be sending JSON along from somewhere else. It doesn't hurt to be safe at the business end of the JSON--where it can be executed.

Comment: The service provider is handing back the json response in the headers along with an oauth_token and oauth_token_secret.  The json contains the person data.  I'm storing the tokens in cookies but I want to take some of the json data and display it in the browser of the user.  I've been using PHP.  Is eval safe for this?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is object notation. Whatever language you're using, you should be able to find a JSON library that can convert back and forth between a string and the object.

If you're using JavaScript, [this code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) should work. The description for usage [is here](http://www.json.org/js.html).